# Not able to hold and scroll up and down the SfListView scroll bar indicator in Android

Tags: listview, xamarin, scroll, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I am working in Xamarin.Forms project and using Syncfusion SfListView control for a list.

For the scrolling in iOS I can hold the scroll bar indicator to scroll up and down. In Android I am not able to hold the scroll bar indicator to scroll up and down.

Could you please give any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

We regret to inform you that as per implementation of SfListview, the ScrollviewRenderer are handled internally in our source. So, workaround to hold and scroll up and down the sflistview scroll bar indicator in android is not possible.

We suggest to use the scrollview outside the listview and set the IsScrollingEnabled property is false and implement the following custom renderer for scrollview in the sample level,

Link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/144713/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-scrollbars-visibility